# How to specify the version of python for building pybind11 module

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I have setup my pybind11 for building python modules written in c++.
I have python3.6, and python3.7 installed on my ubuntu system, I installed both `python3.6-dev` and `python3.7-dev`. then I setup my `cmakelists.txt` file for my project as following:

```
set(PYTHONVERSION "3.7")
# None of the lines below works 
add_definitions(-DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION="${PYTHONVERSION}")
set(PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION ${PYTHONVERSION} CACHE STRING "")
set(PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION ${PYTHONVERSION}) 
find_package(Python ${PYTHONVERSION} COMPONENTS Development Interpreter)

set(TARGET proj)
pybind11_add_module(${TARGET} MODULE proj.cpp)
target_include_directories(${TARGET} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
if (Python_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(${TARGET} PUBLIC ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
```

However, when I build the project it still generates modules for `python3.6` instead of `python3.7`. Below is my output from cmake, I found cmake finds `python3.6` first, where I didn't even call `findpython`.

```
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-9 - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-9 - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Conan: Adjusting output directories
[cmake] -- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
[cmake] -- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
[cmake] -- Conan: Adjusting language standard
[cmake] -- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: /home/mpnv38/develop/parcel_dim_pywrapper/build
[cmake] -- Conan: Compiler GCC>=5, checking major version 9
[cmake] -- Conan: Checking correct version: 9
[cmake] -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "3.6.9") 
[cmake] -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
[cmake] -- Found Python: /usr/bin/python3.7 (found suitable version "3.7.5", minimum required is "3.7") found components: Development Interpreter Development.Module Development.Embed 
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=cmake#cmake-doesn-t-detect-the-right-python-version

Comment: In addition, `set (PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION "3.8")` works perfectly well for me (the default one is 3.7 on my system).